# Scroll animation in vue 3 without a Library

Tags: javascript, vue.js, vuejs3

i found a guide that allows you to create a scroll animation on a web page without having to use a library. Unfortunately the guide was for Vue 2 and not Vue 3. Here is what I have currently created:

main.js

```
import ScrollAnimation from './js/scrollanimation';

createApp(App)
.directive('scrollanimation', ScrollAnimation)
```

js/scrollanimation.js

```
const animatedScrollObserver = new IntersectionObserver(
    (entries, animatedScrollObserver) => {
  
      entries.forEach((entry) => {

        if(entry.isIntersecting) {
          entry.target.classList.add('enter');
          animatedScrollObserver.unobserve(entry.target);
        }
      });
    }
  );
  

  export default {
    bind(el) {
      el.classList.add('before-enter');
      animatedScrollObserver.observe(el);
    }
  }
```

Home.vue

```
<template>
            <header class="w-full h-full flex-wrap md:flex-nowrap flex items-center justify-center pt-32 mb-24 lg:pb-28 lg:mb-48 bg-aere bg-no-repeat bg-contain">
        <div class="w-4/5 md:w-1/2 xl:w-2/5 m-8 md:pr-10 flex justify-center"> 
            <div>
                <h1 class="text-center md:text-left font-strait text-2xl sm:text-3xl lg:text-4xl 2xl:text-5xl pb-4">Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consetetur sadipscing elitr</h1>
                <p class="text-center md:text-left font-opensans text-base 2xl:text-xl font-light">Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consetetur sadipscing elitr, sed diam nonumy eirmod tempor invidunt ut labore et dolore magna aliquyam erat, sed diam voluptua. At vero eos et accusam et justo duo dolores et ea rebum. Stet clita kasd gubergren, no sea takimata sanctus est Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet.</p>
            </div>
        </div>
        <div v-scrollanimation class="w-full md:w-1/2 xl:w-3/5">
            <img src="../assets/header-home.jpg" class="w-full rounded-bl-3xl" alt="">
        </div>

    </header>

<style>
.before-enter {
    opacity: 0;
    transform: translateX(100px);
    transition: all 1s cubic-bezier(.41,.01,.57,1.61);
  }
  .enter {
    opacity: 1;
    transform: translateX(0px);
  }
</style>
```

Sadly it doesn't do anything. Do you have an idea, what could be the problem?

Comment: Do you have a CodeSandbox or jsFiddle ?

Comment: No everything is local, but I could transfer it there. It might just take a while because I have a lot going on at the moment. :)